# Find the variance $Var[\int_0^t(aB_s+bs)^2dB_s]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

How to find the variance $Var[\int_0^t(aB_s+bs)^2dB_s],$ where $B_s$ are standard Brownian motion.

---

My thoughts:

$Var[\int_0^t(aB_s+bs)^2dB_s] = E[(\int_0^t(aB_s+bs)^2dB_s)^2] - E[\int_0^t(aB_s+bs)^2dB_s]^2.$

For the first term, it seems that we need to use Ito's isometry. Then $E[(\int_0^t(aB_s+bs)^2dB_s)^2] = E[\int_0^t (aB_s+bs)^4ds].$ I don't know how to do the next step. Do I need to expand the integrand $(aB_s+bs)^4$ and calculate the integral term by term? If so,
How to calculate $\int_0^t s^i B_s^j dB_s$ ? (Let $f(t,x)=t^ix^j$ and then use ito's formula?)

For the second term, do we just expand the integrand to calculate the integral and then calculate the expectation?

Am I on the right track to solve this problem? Are there an easier way to calculate the variance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that for each $s \geq 0$, $a B_s + bs \sim N(bs, a^2s)$. Thus, its [fourth moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) is given by $$\mathbb{E}[(aB_s + bs)^4] = (bs)^4 + 6(bs)^2(a^2s) + 3(a^2s)^2 = b^4 s^4 + 6a^2b^2s^3 + 3a^4s^2$$

Since an Itô integral has mean zero, the variance of the integral is simply its second moment. By using Itô's isometry and Tonelli's theorem, we get:

$$\begin{align*}
Var \left( \int_0^t (aB_s + bs)^2 dB_s \right) &= \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t (aB_s + bs)^2 dB_s \right)^2 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t (aB_s + bs)^4 ds \right)\\
&=  \int_0^t\mathbb{E} \left(  (aB_s + bs)^4 \right)ds \\
&= \int_0^t b^4 s^4 + 6a^2b^2s^3 + 3a^4s^2 ds \\
&= \frac{b^4t^5}{5} + \frac{6a^2 b^2 t^4}{4} + a^4t^2 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that there's a typo. I think the last term of $\mathbb{E}[(aB_s + bs)^4]$ should be $3a^4s^2.$

Comment: @XYZ You're right, thanks for spotting that. I've now corrected the typo.